# Maven "versions" plugin exclusion

Tags: java, maven, versions-maven-plugin

I am trying unsuccessfully to exclude packages when displaying/updating versions and I don't get why.

I have a project:

```
<groupId>my.group</groupId>
<artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
```

which in the pluginManagement section declares:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com.atlassian.confluence:confluence:*</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
        <allowSnapshots>false</allowSnapshots>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

A second plugin is having the above as parent:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
```

But when I invoke `mvn versions:display-dependencies-update`, it still reports:

```
com.atlassian.confluence:confluence ..... 5.10.1 -> 6.0.0-viqueen-m001
```

In case I use a ruleset in the configuration I get error that file is not found (since it is located in the parent pom folder) and cant copy/share cause parent has packaging pom.

I was not able to exclude neither using `-DexcludesList` nor replacing the `<excludes>` section with `<excludesList>`. I could only assume that I have a typo in the group:artifact but I have copied over plenty times to avoid such.

Any ideas except having ruleset in the network?

Edit:
As per comment effective-pom is:

```xml
<pluginManagement>
.
.
.
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <includes>
          <include>my.group</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>com.atlassian.confluence:confluence:*</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
        <allowSnapshots>false</allowSnapshots>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
</pluginManagement>
```

and versions is not mentioned anywhere else.

Comment: Please look what show `mvn help:effective-pom`

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: have you managed to find a solution?? I have a very similar issue with the same plugin:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954730/excludeslist-parameter-usage-in-versionsupdate-properties

Comment: As of now this functionality is not part of the "versions:display-dependencies-update" goal.
You can vote for this to be included: https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/318

Answer (score 0):

## Problem statement

If I understand correctly, you would like to exclude some dependencies from the consideration of the `versions:display-dependencies-update` Maven goal of the Versions Maven Plugin.

## Introduction

Let's consider the following version as the current Maven plugin version:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.2</version>
</plugin>
```

## Possible solution

Use the corresponding parameters of the Maven goal, which are available since the `2.12.0` version of the Maven plugin:

- `dependencyExcludes`. [Source](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions/blob/2.14.2/versions-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/versions/DisplayDependencyUpdatesMojo.java#L176-L196).
- `dependencyManagementExcludes`. [Source](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions/blob/2.14.2/versions-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/versions/DisplayDependencyUpdatesMojo.java#L124-L144).

Here is a draft example Maven plugin configuration for your case:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <dependencyManagementExcludes>com.atlassian.confluence:confluence</dependencyManagementExcludes>
        <dependencyExcludes>com.atlassian.confluence:confluence</dependencyExcludes>
        <…>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```