# excludesList parameter usage in versions:update-properties

Tags: maven, versions-maven-plugin

I have the following in my pom:

```
.
.
<properties>
    <x.version>1.1</x.version>
    <y.version>1.2</y.version>
    <z.version>1.3</z.version>
</properties>
.
.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
.
.
```

I want to use `exludesList` (or `includesList`) to update the version of only `x` (and keep `y` and `z` to be updated manually).

I have done the following:

```
.
.
<properties>
    <x.version>1.1</x.version>
    <y.version>1.2</y.version>
    <z.version>1.3</z.version>
    <versions.excludesList>
        y_groupId:y_artifactId*,
        z_groupId:z_artifactId*
    </versions.excludesList>
</properties>
.
.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludesList>
            ${versions.excludesList}
        </excludesList>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
.
.
```

and I am running the following command (which update everything):
`mvn -U versions:update-properties -e scm:diff -e "-Dmessage=updated version numbers" scm:checkin`

I have tried to simplify it by using only one item with `excludes`  as `excludesList` seems to be for command line only as mentioned [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html#excludesList) :

```
    .
.
<properties>
    <x.version>1.1</x.version>
    <y.version>1.2</y.version>
    <z.version>1.3</z.version>
</properties>
.
.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>y_groupId:y_artifactId*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
.
.
```

And it's not working although I am using it the same way it used in [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/advancing-dependency-versions.html).I am not sure what bit I am not using right.

I have also tried to add `-Dexcludes=y_groupId:y_artifactId*` to the command and it doesn't seem to be working either.

note: the above is a simplified version, I got a lot of modules, I don't want to edit my command, I need to do everything in the pom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as easy as adding the version:

```
.
.
<properties>
    <x.version>1.1</x.version>
    <y.version>1.2</y.version>
    <z.version>1.3</z.version>
</properties>
.
.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>y_groupId:y_artifactId*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
.
.
```